# Transform column-wise table to row-wise

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a table designed in column wise format as below:

| Category | 2023 Jan Rev | 2023 Jan GM | 2023 Feb Rev | 2023 Feb GM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Labour | 3512610 | 702522 | 789456 | 157891.2 |
| Equipment | 2450 | 490 | 459 | 91.8 |
| Materials | 1635 | 327 | 324 | 64.8 |

how can I best get row-wise format like this:

```
Category  | Period   | Rev      | GM
__________ __________ __________ ___________
Labour    | Jan 2023 | 3512610  | 702522    
Equipment | Jan 2023 | 2450     | 490
Materials | Jan 2023 | 1635     | 327
Labour    | Feb 2023 | 789456   | 157891.2
Equipment | Feb 2023 | 459      | 91.8
Materials | Feb 2023 | 324      | 64.8
```

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the first column and choose **upivot other columns**
Then right click the attribute column **split column .. by positions** and use 0,9 to get columns. Right click the type column use **transform .. pivot column ..** and choose the numbers as the value column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Positions" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 9}), {"YearMonth", "Type"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Positions",{{"YearMonth", type date}, {"Type", type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Type]), "Type", "Value", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Think the answer needs a final pivot but have an upvote as it is basically there.

Comment: Ah. Didnt notice. Yep. Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category", type text}, {"2023 Jan Revenue", Int64.Type}, {"2023 Jan Gross Margin", Int64.Type}, {"2023 Feb Revenue", Int64.Type}, {"2023 Feb Gross Margin", type number}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Inserted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Period", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Attribute], " ", 1), type text),
    #"Extracted Text After Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Inserted Text Before Delimiter", {{"Attribute", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, " ", 1), type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Extracted Text After Delimiter", List.Distinct(#"Extracted Text After Delimiter"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, using Power Query.

1. Unpivot all columns, EXCEPT the first column (Category). Now we
   should have 3 columns: **Category**, **New Column 1** ( contains 2023 Jan
   Rev,    2023 Jan GM 2023, Feb Rev,  2023 Feb GM) and **New Column 2**
   (contains value number)
2. Second: Split New Column 1 into 2 columns:
   **Period** (Jan 2023, Feb 2023) and **Attribute** (Rev, GM)
3. Pivot the **Attribute** columns, now we have 2 columns **Rev** and **GM**

Comment: excellent! good job